# What is the python equivalent of SQL code - 'Select a,max(b) from table ...'

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get the equivalent of the below SQL code in python.

This may be a fairly simple question but I have recently shifted from SQL to python and I need help!

```sql
select h.name, max(h.date) as last_visit
from table1 n join table2 h on n.id=h.id
group by 1
```

In table2, there are multiple names and dates. The same name can be associated with multiple dates.  I just want to extract the last date per name from table2 where the entries match that in table1 as well (table1 just contains certain names). For this, I have created 2 dataframes, table1 and table2, but i can't figure out how to proceed from here.

Comment: What do you mean saying "shifted from SQL to python"? Are your data now Python objects?

Comment: Yeah, instead of tables i now have excel sheets which i have read into dataframes. Usually I can filter data in tables using SQL but I am not sure how to do the same stuff in python. I can load the data into the database and use sql, but I was wondering how to do it in python as it would save me the time to load the data into the database and the work on it.

Comment: I would just put them _back_ into a proper database, which is sqlite3 bundled with Python, and continued to run the known-working queries. Maybe I'd created a few indexes where it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks @9000. I did just that as I couldn't figure a way to perform the required filtering in Python. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out a way to do it:

```
a=pd.merge(table1['name','date'],table2['id'],how='inner',on='id')
ind=a.groupby['name']('date').max().to_frame(name = 'date').reset_index()
```